# adding a component to a c# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

it's been a long while since I've written a winform application - so forgive me if I'm a bit out of my element here :)

I found this component http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14841/How-to-write-a-loading-circle-animation-in-NET which generates an ajax like loader for a winform application.

I've downloaded and have the compiled dll file. how can I import it to my toolbox and use it in my winform project?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer find references, right click, and select "Add Reference". Browse to the dll and the controls should automatically be added to your tool box.

Comment: I think you'd also need to build the solution after that, only then the control will appear in the toolbox.

Comment: @Joker_vD I think that depends on the version of Visual Studio, but don't quote me on that, it's been awhile since I used an external dll that added WinForm controls.

Answer (score 0):

ok... simple solutions (I feel stupid now :) )

right click on an empty space on the toolbox window -> select "choose items" -> browse for that dll.

that's it.

for some reason it didn't work on first try. but it did now.